# vb.net sessionState sessionIdManagerType CustomAssemblyNameInBinFolder value in webconfig

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I've been trying to implement the following example from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.createsessionid.aspx). I can't seem to get the page to load and I know it's due to the changes I've made in the webconfig. Does anyone have an example or an explanation for the "CustomAssemblyNameInBinFolder" property?

```
sessionIDManagerType="Your.ID.Manager.Type, CustomAssemblyNameInBinFolder"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does anyone have an example or an explanation for the "CustomAssemblyNameInBinFolder" property?*

It's the name of the assembly in which the type is defined.  For example, if there is a DLL in your solution named "Foo.dll" containing the type `Your.ID.Manager.Type`, the property would read:

```
sessionIDManagerType="Your.ID.Manager.Type, Foo"
```

> You can specify a type name by using the CLR standard type name syntax, as shown in the following example:
>
> <namespace>.<typename>, <assembly>

[Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507491(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful